# Ubuntu ACPI BIOS Error

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, gnome, acpi

I am having problem with Ubuntu installation in my ASUS TUF Dash Laptop.

The following error messages appear on boot, and GNOME does not start up.

```
[    3.156095] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\CTDP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20201113/psargs-330)
[    3.156103] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.IETM.IDSP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20201113/psparse-529)
[    3.156103] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.IETM._OSC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20201113/psparse-529)
```

It is strange that I can switch to other ttys by Ctrl+Alt+F2345, and then I come back to tty1, GNOME starts properly.

BIOS Firmware is up-to-date, and Windows 11 is also installed alongside. The last time I dual-booted Ubuntu with Windows 11, even with some minor errors that looked similar to error messages above, it *did* boot well. So I think there are no compatibility issues between Ubuntu and Windows 11. Maybe the BIOS is not *fully* compatible with Ubuntu but I am not sure.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Windows 11? Are you sure?

Comment: Yes, with Windows Insiders Dev channel

Comment: My Asus boots just fine with error messages like yours.
Please check if you have a Mediatek wireless card installed in your laptop.
Then grep your logs to check if they contain UBSAN errors like this:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1961466